# Initialize a Rectangle inside a class

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak, gnu-smalltalk

I have a class named `Map`. I want to initialize a rectangle from the `Rectangle` class `origin: 0 @ 0 corners: 50 @ 40` inside the `Map`. So, when I try in workspace as

```
myMap := Map new.
```

it should return me `(0 @ 0) corner: (50 @ 40)`.

I have tried:

`initialize
    Rectangle origin: 0@0  corner: 100@100.`

but it didn't work? any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, if you want to initialise the instance variable, then you have to define it first:

```
Object subclass: #Map
  instanceVariableNames: 'rectangle'
  ...
```

and then you initialise it:

```
initialize
  rectangle := Rectangle origin: 0@0  corner: 100@100.
```

Now if you want to subclass `Rectangle`, and want to initialise your map with `0@0  corner: 100@100` by default you do:

```
initialize
  self setOrigin: 0@0 corner: 100@100
```